# Add hashtag before each keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am a newbie in coding JS and hope someone can guide me to the right direction of my keyword system. Below are the requirements for keyword text field's behavior.

1. Only non-symbol character (includes letter, digit and other countries' languages) and space are allowed. If any symbols are entered, it should be replaced by '' / the input text will not display the symbols.
2. the hash (#) should be added instantly when the first non-symbol character of keyword is entered.
3. the keyword is separated by a space

Below are my codes:

```js
function hashtag() {
  str = document.getElementById('tagid').value;
  tagged = str.replace(/#/g, '').replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g, '#' + '$1');
  document.getElementById('tagid').value = tagged;
}
```

```html
Enter keyword:
<input type="text" name="tag" id="tagid" onkeypress="hashtag();" />
```

The problem are, the hash (#) can only be added when I entered the second non-symbol character / a space, but not the first one. And, there is no handling for symbols' input and no hash added before other countries languages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define "symbol"?

Comment: Those non-language (e.g. English, Japanese, Korean, etc), non-digit characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first issue of the hash only being applied on the second press, you can use `onkeyup="hashtag();"` to execute the action after the keypress, once the text has been added to the input field and can then be evaluated.

[Here is some documentation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events#key-event-properties) on JavaScript keypress events that may be helpful.

For removing symbols whilst still allowing foreign characters, I couldn't find anything great in pure js (PHP has ways to work around this which is interesting), so I've taken a different route of deleting all excluded characters (hopefully, if there's more please edit in to make more complete) and then "hash-tagging" everything else that isn't a space.

This would leave you with a function like this:

```
function hashtag() { 
    str = document.getElementById('tagid').value;
    str = str.replace(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.@#£\/]/g, '');
    tagged = str.replace(/#/g, '').replace(/([^" "]+)/g, '#'+'$1');
    document.getElementById('tagid').value = tagged;
}
```

Here's the complete code that you can run within the answer:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HashTag</title>
<SCRIPT TYPE="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT"> 

function hashtag() { 
    str = document.getElementById('tagid').value;
    str = str.replace(/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.@#£\/]/g, '');
    tagged = str.replace(/#/g, '').replace(/([^" "]+)/g, '#'+'$1');
    document.getElementById('tagid').value = tagged;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

Enter keyword: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="tag" id="tagid" onkeyup="hashtag();"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried to keep as much of your original code as possible, please let me know if there are any other issues and I'll be happy to try to fix them.

Comment: Thank you! The input problem fixed. If it allows non-English language characters' input, it would be perfect!

Comment: Hey @MiuMiu , I've added functionality into the code to allow foreign symbols, I had to take a different approach though that I'm not very happy with, if you see anything better please do suggest it. if this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help others in the future.

Comment: Appreciate for your great help! Your solution works well for most languages I tested. For those language having 2 or more byte characters (e.g. Traditional Chinese), I just add _ for the last replace regex (i.e. replace(/([^" "_]+)/g) then problem solved. (P.S. not sure adding _ is the correct way or not but it works for my case)

Comment: That's great, I'm happy to hear it works for you, if you come across anything better feel free to edit it in or ask for me to and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet that should work.  My changes are:

- Use `onkeydown` instead of `onkeyup` to trigger the function.  `onkeydown` fires *before* the letter has been inserted into the text field and so the function doesn't see the key you just typed.
- Use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g` as the regex.  `^` means "anything but", so basically you're removing everything except the characters listed there. You could also use `[^\w]/g` but that would also allow the underscore which may or may not want.
- Add an extra step to preappend the `#` because the above step removes it.  (may seem wasteful but it's elegant and plenty fast enough)

```js
function hashtag() {
  
  //get the current contents of the text field
  var str = document.getElementById('tagid').value;
  
  //strip any non-word characters (will also strip hash symbol)
  str = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
  
  //add the hash symbol back
  str = '#' + str;
  
  //update the text field
  document.getElementById('tagid').value = str;
}
```

```html
Enter keyword:
<input type="text" name="tag" id="tagid" onkeyup="hashtag();" />
```

Comment: @MiuMiu Did you try it?  It doesn't allow spaces for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. bind to onkeyup event
2. replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` by `\w+`
3. for foreign symbols, you will have to add them one by one (I tried to put as many as I could find):
4. I added the i flag for your regex, you won't have to worry about uppercase letters like 'Â' as long as you have the lower case one

```js
function hashtag() { 
    str = document.getElementById('tagid').value;
    tagged = str.replace(/#/g, '').replace(/([\wâàãäéèêëîìôòõòùûüñ]+)/gi, '#'+'$1');
    document.getElementById('tagid').value = tagged;
}
```

```html
Enter keyword: <input TYPE="text" NAME="tag" id="tagid" onkeyup="hashtag();"/>
```

Edit :

not sure if you want to keep or remove special characters, here is a version were special chars are removed :

```js
function hashtag() { 
    str = document.getElementById('tagid').value;
    // remove things
    str = str.replace(/[^\w ]/g, '');
    tagged = str.replace(/(\w+)/gi, '#'+'$1');
    document.getElementById('tagid').value = tagged;
}
```

```html
Enter keyword: <input TYPE="text" NAME="tag" id="tagid" onkeyup="hashtag();"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for remind me to use \w. I still have question about displaying non-English language, should I add all unicode character set I want (e.g. \u0080-\uFFFF, \u0e00-\u0e7f) or does any simple expression can do so?